# How to initialise date time object from date time (string) in NetSuite (User Event - server side script)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

Here, I have string date_time as "2022-10-27T01:35:48.354z" , the same and time i need to initialise as date time object with same and time as in given string.

I have tried
new Date() in javascript,
format.parse, format.format in suitescript,
moment library file too, but still could not get solution.
Please help me on this. I will be thankful.

Comment: `new Date('2022-10-27T01:35:48.354z')` works to create a Date object. Can you show more code that includes using the created date and where it fails?